# How to set up a make file with environment variable $BOOST_HOME

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, makefile, environment-variables

I need to setup a make file to compile my code with the environment variable $BOOST_HOME pointing to the boost install directory. Currently I am compiling using the command

```
g++ -std=c++0x -Wno-deprecated main.cpp
```

How would I go about doing this, so that my code will compile for others if their boost install directory is different from mine?

Comment: That command does not appear to use the variable `BOOST_HOME`. Is that the command you want to use?

Comment: That is the command I am using to compile my code, however I need to give this code to my professor who may have boost installed in a different location, they said we would need to give a make file using the variable $BOOST_HOME which points to the boost install directory

Comment: So you have two problems: 1) how to tell the compiler where to find the boost library, and 2) how to write a makefile that will pass a given command to the compiler. Do you know how to do either of these?

Comment: @Beta No I don't.

Comment: I can help with the second part, not the first-- I've never used Boost.